# Finding abbreviations from data in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a MYSQL database table (named QuestionAnswer) which contains two columns (questions and answers).

Data in 'answers' columns are in the format of "The full form of EPL is English Premier League" OR "This sentence has no abbreviations".

I need to check if any abbreviations exist in the answers column i.e. I want to find all words that are in all Uppercase. I need query for all the columns with abbreviations like EPL. Can anyone suggest how?

Comment: yOU CAN USE `LIKE '%EPL%`

Comment: you can use like search. see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html

Comment: But the problem is I don't know the list of all abbreviations. I want to find all words that are in all Uppercase. Sorry if i failed to mention that properly in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that an abbreviation is a 'word in all capital letters', try this:

```
SELECT * FROM QuestionAnswer
WHERE answers REGEXP BINARY '\s*[A-Z]{2,}\s*'
```

Working demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6e59d/9

"REGEXP is not case sensitive, except when used with **binary** strings". Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Comment: `\b` will not work properly in MySQL, and, also, this will capture single upper-chars, like `"I am here"` - no abbreviations here, obviously

Comment: @AlmaDo how about using `BINARY` for case-sensitivity?

Comment: Yes, it will work, but causing [coercions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-collation-expressions.html) in case when original string has another collation. Normally, as I recall, it will not be problem, but still I'd not recommend that in common case.

Comment: I replaced `EPL is English Premier League` with `EPC is English Premier League` and it still appears in result, All this do is to fetch records that have upper case word...

Comment: @DharmeshPatel OP explained in the comments that "I want to find all words that are in all Uppercase". Based on this comment, this answer works perfectly fine for the OP and thus it was accepted.